# CSS - How to fix one section and other moving?

Tags: angular, css

I am using https://bertrandg.github.io/angular-split/#/ for my requirement. It solved half of my problem.

I have 2 sections, using this angular-split I spliced into two. After 70% width, second section should overlap first. Means, first section is fixed and second section can be able to drag over first.

`Eg`: min-width of 1st section is 70%, if I drag second section more than 30% width, this should override first section.

Program follows:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tlO2b85xXGIUdga6J9o8?p=preview

Right section min-width should be 30% and max-width - 50%

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I updated your `app.ts` also forked your plunker ... link is mentioned below. I think this should do what you want.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {AngularSplitModule} from 'angular-split';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; background: rgba(0,0,10, .4); border: 4px solid rgba(15, 15,211, .4);">
        <split direction="horizontal" style="border:2px solid black;position:relative;">
            <split-area size="70" >
                <p style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:50%;z-index:-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tiam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </split-area>
            <split-area size="30">
                <p style="background:red;">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eodolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
            </split-area>
        </split>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, AngularSplitModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/w8O2I3bD4bdXp0QsL35L?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With this I want to configure max-width and min-width of sections. `Eg`: right section min-width should be 30% and max-width - 50%

Comment: And `z-index:-1`, I am not able to use, it's disabling left section. I will be having some click actions in left section.

Comment: It's looks like min/max functionality is not provided in plugin... for that you need to look for some different plugin...

Comment: oh,I fixed the `z-index` thing.